# What is this citation style called?

Tags: style, citations

What is this citation style called:

> P. Schmid-Saugeon, J. guillod & J.P.
>   Thiran, Towards a Computer-Aided
>   Diagnosis System For Pigmented Skin
>   Lesions, Computerized Medical Imaging
>   and Graphics, Vol 27, pp. 65–78,
>   (2003) .

Thanks.

Comment: it will be helpful if you break it down alon gthe lines of "Author First Author Last, Author First, Author Last, Title, Journal, Volumn Number, Pages, Year published"

Comment: Choose: http://library.concordia.ca/help/howto/citations.html

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an APA format cite for a journal.